# How to reference a progressbar inside a CollectionView?

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a CollectionView, on its data template has a progressbar. I'm able to find the respective element index of ObservableCollection but how can I reference its respective ProgressBar view? I need call method ProgressTo(), or may I simply bind the progress property to a property of the item on collection?

Comment: You can't reference items inside of a template directly.  You need to use databinding.

Comment: So, no chance to call ProgressTo? This method gives a good visual effect lol.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid hat you can not use ProgressTo directly, because you can not access Progreeebar control in CollectionView directly.

If you still want to get ProgressBar, and call ProgressTo() method, you can consider to add Button in CollectionView datatemplate, like this:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding barmodels}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding str}" />
                        <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding value}" />
                        <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" Text="btn1" />
                    </StackLayout>

                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Then you can get current ProgressBar control by Button.Click.

```
 public partial class Page7 : ContentPage
{
    public ObservableCollection<barmodel> barmodels { get; set; }
    public Page7()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        barmodels = new ObservableCollection<barmodel>()
        {
            new barmodel(){str="test 1",value=0.1},
            new barmodel(){str="test 2",value=0.2},
            new barmodel(){str="test 3",value=0.3},
            new barmodel(){str="test 4",value=0.4},
            new barmodel(){str="test 5",value=0.5}
        };
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }  
    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // access buttonclickhandler  
        var buttonClickHandler = (Button)sender;

        // access Parent Layout for Button  
        StackLayout ParentStackLayout = (StackLayout)buttonClickHandler.Parent;
        ProgressBar progressbar = (ProgressBar)ParentStackLayout.Children[1];
        progressbar.ProgressTo(0.75, 500, Easing.Linear);
    }
}

public class barmodel
{
    public string str { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

But I don't suggest you to do it, I think use binding Progress for ProgressBar is the best way.

Comment: Hey, Cherry. Thank you for that. I will follow your advice and go ahead with binding, but I'm stuck on a new challenge the result of division is always 0 and then, suddenly it gets 1, so the progress bar goes from 0 directly to 1. How can I force it to have this format: 0.1.... 0.5..... 0.8 .... 1.0?

```For example,  161 / 750090  or  244 / 750090 is always 0```

I think it's being rounded to down and result is always 0

Comment: @ÉderRochaBezerra I guess that the value is very very small, so it can not display effect.